# Fill every word in a qword using corresponding high bit of each word

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, x86-64, bitwise-operators, bitmask

I have a qword. It consists of 4 parts -- 16 bits each.

Each part has a structure: the first bit of every part is either 1 or 0, others are zeros.

I want to broadcast that first bit to all the other positions with that 16-bit element.

[image: For example]

Comment: An arithmetic right shift would do it. Is this in any particular language?

Comment: @harold , asm x64. Could you please explain how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In x64 assembly you can apply arithmetic right shift on a per-word basis:

```
psraw xmm0, 15
```

This actually processes two of such qwords side by side, but you can use it for only one. For example, maybe that qword is in memory somewhere, then you can do:

```
movq xmm0, [somewhere]
psraw xmm0, 15
movq [somewhere], xmm0
```

This can be used to and from a general purpose register as well.

---

Without SSE, even generically (eg using operations that exist in typical higher level languages as well), there are other options. These all assume that the input `x` has the specified form, with no stray 1's, only the top bit of every word is allowed to ever be 1. The code above can have arbitrary junk in the other bits.

When implemented literally (with a real multiplication), this still only uses one register. The shift is a logical shift. In a higher level language, the multiplication may be compiled to something else:

```
(x >> 15) * 0xFFFF
```

Maybe faster, depending on the cost of multiplication, but needs a temporary register:

```
(x << 1) - (x >> 15)
```

A more brute force way, with no practical use as far as I know, but may be interesting:

```
x |= x >> 8
x |= x >> 4
x |= x >> 2
x |= x >> 1
```

Comment: Nice! But maybe there is a way to do that without using SSE, just with bit operators?

Comment: @IlyaKirillov ok I've added some

Comment: At least on `clang` and `gcc` the [shift version](https://godbolt.org/g/DjtTdD) turns out slightly better than the `mul` version, at least when isolated in a function since the compiler can use `lea` to do the `(x << 1)` into a distinct register, saving a `mov`. Both compilers decide to do the `* 0xFFFF` with two shifts and a `sub`. I included `mul2` to show what it might look like if `mul` were used: only two instructions but longer latency. Oddly `gcc` inserted an apparently pointless `mov` in that case, but not if you remove `-march=haswell`.